# Error: failed to load external entity

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to R.  I'm trying to run the script from this site.
http://www.thertrader.com/category/trading-strategies/

I've gotten this far (not too far at all).

```
library(tseries)
library(quantmod)
library(XML)

startDate <- "2005-01-01"
tables <- readHTMLTable("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies")
```

> Error: failed to load external entity

Can someone help me get this working?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a weird error in the way `readHTMLTable` is trying to access the internet (I'm getting the same error). As a workaround, try using `httr` to download and then parse using `readHTMLTable`:

```
library(httr)
tables <- GET("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies")
tables <- readHTMLTable(rawToChar(tables$content))
```